# Mysql - Verify if part of a result exists in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, search

I have two tables in Mysql, one is all the data I need to display to users and in another simply a list of URLs of the items that were deleted.

What I want to do is select all the results as long as the element does not exist in the "deleted items" table.

In my table of "Deleted_Items" I have a list of URLs of the type

```
https://example.com/video/123456/
```

But in my table "Items" the URL column contains the following:

```
https://example.com/video/123456/dogs_and_cats/
```

I would need to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
SELECT id, url, thumb FROM Items
WHERE Items.url NOT CONTAINS Deleted_Items.url
```

P.S:
I had a similar case with two other tables but the difference was that in the "Items" table I had a list of IDs and in the "Deleted_Items" table I also had a list of IDs, so I applied the following query:

```
SELECT id, url, thumb
FROM Items
LEFT OUTER JOIN Deleted_Items 
ON (Items.url = Deleted_Items.url) 
WHERE Deleted_Items.url IS NULL
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Use the same anti-join pattern as with the "list of IDs" query. Seems like the matching condition (in the ON clause) would be something like this  `ON items.url LIKE CONCAT('%',deleted_items.url,'%')`. (Potential gotchas  with LIKE comparison is the `_` and `%` wildcards.) Alternatives to the `LIKE` comparison would be a regular expression comparison `REGEXP` (with even more complex rules with special characters), or make use of `INSTR()` or `LOCATE()` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a left join  check for deleted_item.url is null

```
 SELECT Items.id, Items.url, .Itemsthumb 
 FROM Items
 LEFT JOIN deleted_Items  ON Items.url  = deleted_Items.url
 where deleted_Items.url is null
```

looking to  your added  data sample could be you need  a like comparision

```
 SELECT Items.id, Items.url, .Itemsthumb 
 FROM Items
 LEFT JOIN deleted_Items  ON  deleted_Items.url like concat(Items.url , '%')
 where deleted_Items.url is null
```

Comment: But there will be some problem in the comparison ?.
The URL list in "Deleted_Items" contains urls of the type "https://example.com/video/123456/" and the "Items" contains urls of type "https://example.com/video/123456/dogs_and_cats "

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works but for some reason does not work when I try to add an "ORDER BY ..." The sentence takes a long time to work.

Comment: if the query work without order by and produce the correct (not ordered) result this mean that the query work  correctly .and you should rate tha answer  as right and /or as useful at least .. . if the query with  or without order by is slow  this is another question and you should post a new question  specifically related to the performance .. change the term of the question after have obtained  a right question is not  fair  ..